# How to merge multiple datasets without getting empty cells? (And Result to the top)

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, dataset, devexpress

For example I have 3 different datasets out of my database. Their primary key can be set or not and the name can be different.

My Code look this so far:

```
public static DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView m_ActiveIdeenkasten = null;
public DocManager()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    LoadDockPanels();

    m_ActiveIdeenkasten = gridView1;

    DataSet dt1 = new DataSet();
    DataSet dt2 = new DataSet();
    DataSet dt3 = new DataSet();

    dt1 = SQL.GetDataset("SELECT ik_bezeichnung FROM IK_Ideenkasten");
    dt2 = SQL.GetDataset("SELECT pm_artikel FROM PM_Startseite");
    dt3 = SQL.GetDataset("SELECT * FROM IK_Status");

    DataSet dt = new DataSet();

    dt.Merge(dt1, true , MissingSchemaAction.Add);
    dt.Merge(dt2, true, MissingSchemaAction.Add);
    dt.Merge(dt3, true, MissingSchemaAction.Add);

    m_ActiveIdeenkasten.GridControl.DataSource = dt.Tables[0];
}
```

Now I have a problem, my `dt1` has many rows and if I merge `dt2` and `dt3` together with `dt`, my gridview looks messed up.

[image: Picture of Result: Gridview]

You see there are many empty cells which I don't want. The purpose of all these should be for customizable DockPanel for users. Where each dockpanel can contain different columns out of the database how the user wants it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ik_bezuwichnung FROM IK_Ideenkasten WHERE ik_bezichnung IS NOT NULL;
SELECT pm_artikel FROM PM_Startseite WHERE PM_Startseite IS NOT NULL;
```

And for `IK_Status` you have to manually check in which column the NULL appears and then write that SQL-line with `IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: Its, still happens :/ I think its merging problem